# posting nested values using javascript (php example provided)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, post, xmlhttprequest

I have some PHP code that posts data to an API, and compiles the POST information for curl as follows:

```
<?php
$post_data['field'] = 'fieldsValue';
$post_data['field2'] = 'field2sValue';
$post_data['parameters']['limit'] = '10';
$post_data['parameters']['offset'] = '10';
$post_data['parameters']['search'] = 'value';
?>
```

How would one achieve the same nested parameters to accommodate ['parameters']['limit'] and ['parameters']['offset'] values in a javascript post using XMLHttpRequest?

Code so far:

```
<script>
function fieldSearch(query){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var postdata = "field=fieldsvalue&field2=field2sValue";
    xhttp.open("POST", "app.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postdata.length);
    xhttp.send(postdata);
}
</script>
```

Comment: are you saying you want the post variable to be like this `$_POST['parameters']['limit']` ?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to notate my objects so that they are in nested keyed arrays... essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try create this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      <script type="text/javascript">

          function formSubmit(frmElement){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onload = function(){alert(xhr.responseText);}
            xhr.open(frmElement.method, frmElement.action,true);
            xhr.send(new FormData(frmElement));
            return false;
          }
      </script>

</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="app.php" onsubmit="return formSubmit(this);">
    <input type="text" name="field"/>
    <input type="text" name="field2"/>
    <input type="text" name="parameters[limit]"/>
    <input type="text" name="parameters[offset]"/>
    <input type="text" name="parameters[search]"/>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that works. I can just hide forms as needed. thanks!